# Extract value from websocket response

Tags: regex, performance, jmeter

Im getting this response from a websocket

> a["MESSAGE\ndestination:/user/p0000450/queue/bets/place/status\ncontent-type:application/json\nsubscription:/queue/bets/place/status-1\nmessage-id:p0000450-79\ncontent-length:139\n\n{"id":"c00656b318","groupId":"113686950","status":"PLACED","code":"0","message":"BetSlip with No.113686950 has been accepted","context":{}}\u0000"]

I would like to extract the betslip no.
Cant seem to generate regex that will extract this? please assist

i am planning to use regex extractor and beanshell postprocessor to save the data to excel for all responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the provided info it's hard to figure out all the possible formats of the "betslip number", but try this:

`\bBetSlip with No\.\s*(\d+)\b`

It captures any number of digits before the `"BetSlip with No."`-string.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/NKfVm4/1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be just going for the [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor), all you need to do is to provide "left" and "right" boundaries and JMeter will fetch everything in-between:

So if you give:

- Left boundary as `BetSlip with No.`
- and right boundary as  `has been accepted`

[image]

you will get what you're looking for.

If you have to do this using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) you can go for something like:

```
BetSlip with No.(\d+) has been accepted
```

[image]

Where:

- `()` - grouping
- `d` - matches any digit
- `+` - repetition
- `\` - escape of meta character

More information: [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)